# Is there a way to connect an Eve instance to a Compose mongo cluster over SSL?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, ssl, eve

I didn't see any Eve [documentation](http://python-eve.org/) on connecting to multiple hosts or using ssl. Attempted to use some examples from pymongo but still no luck. I was however able to connect to the instance using only pymongo. Has anyone else dealt with this before?

```
# ENV: mongodb://<username>:<password>@aws-us-east-1-portal.28.dblayer.com:22986,aws-us-east-1-portal.29.dblayer.com:22986/admin?ssl=true

MONGO_URI = os.environ.get('MONGODB_URL', 'mongodb://localhost:27017/psgr')
MONGO_OPTIONS = {'connect': True, 'tz_aware': True, 'ssl_ca_certs': "./servercert.crt"}
```

Comment: Thanks -- this was clutch for getting eve to work with a mongodb hosted in azure cosmos db